# Is there a way to switch the output sound of the beep program to the normal loud speaker instead of beeper?

Tags: command-line, drivers, sound

I installed the beep program (from normal rep) on my ubuntu 18.04 (
[beep manual](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man1/beep.1.html) )

After `modprobe pcspkr` everything was OK. But it has been heard from my very small beeper from the PC's box only. Is there a way to hear it from normal music loud speaker as like any mp3, youtube etc?

I note the `echo -e '\007'` bell command from my shell is normaly heard from music loud speaker, it is very useful for me.

Using of `-e` option of `beep` program didn't help.